# Scrollview "adopts" the height of one list item

Tags: android, listview, android-scrollview

I have a fragment with the ListView of items. This ListView is in ScrollView. When I start my app, scrollview adopts the height of one list item. What can I do to expand ScrollView to full screen?

My xml of fragment:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/lvData"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    </ListView>
</ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Xml of list item:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<FrameLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginTop="10dp">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="45dp"
    android:layout_height="45dp"
    android:id="@+id/tv_number"
    android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/oval"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textIsSelectable="false"
    android:textStyle="normal|bold"
    android:textSize="40sp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:text="@string/number"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    tools:targetApi="jelly_bean_mr1" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/lesson_name"
    android:id="@+id/tv_lesson"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|top"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textStyle="normal|bold"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    tools:targetApi="jelly_bean_mr1" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Время"
    android:id="@+id/tv_time"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/teacher_name"
    android:id="@+id/tv_teacher"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|bottom"
    android:textStyle="italic" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Кабинет"
    android:id="@+id/tv_cab"
    android:layout_gravity="right|bottom"
    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="17dp" />
</FrameLayout>
```

Screenshots

```
https://i.stack.imgur.com/dSbaB.jpg
https://i.stack.imgur.com/fsgd3.jpg
http://i.stac k.imgur.com/oVKGJ.jpg
```

Comment: Can you add a screenshot for more details? thanks :)

Comment: hi also can you explain why you need to put the list inside scroll view

Comment: @RachikAbidi i have added screenshots links

Comment: @Hala.m this is for small height screens

Comment: the list will scroll on its own you don't need the scroll view

Comment: A listview is already scrollable so it does not need to be put inside a scrollview.

Comment: Take a look at this [Discussion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3495890/how-can-i-put-a-listview-into-a-scrollview-without-it-collapsing?rq=1)

Comment: @Hala.m, i have removed scrollview but my problem doesnt solved.

Comment: can you update the question and add the activity layout also?

Comment: @Hala.m i have update the app and everything is working

Comment: @Hala.m but i have another question to you. How I can put numbers to the centers of circles?  Circles are backgrounds of number textviews.

Comment: add the circle as bg and set the gravity of textview to center

Comment: @Hala.m, it is not working for me. text and bg moves to the center of item. What I need to do else?

Comment: did you fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is a bad idea to encase list view inside a scroll view.
you don't need the scroll view the list will scroll on its own and also will Adapt to screen size so just remove the scroll layout and the list view will fill the screen
so the layout will be

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/lvData"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
</ListView>
</RelativeLayout>
```